# Web Api: Access-Control-Allow-Origin Not present error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, cors

This code works with no errors.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CreateItem/{Id}")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateItem(Int64 Id)
{
     //Do Something

     return Ok();
}
```

However, as soon as I introduce async call I get an error saying:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CreateItem/{Id}")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateItem(Int64 Id)
{
     //Do Something
     AsyncCall();
     return Ok();
}
async void AsyncCall(){
     //Parallel job to be done. Doesn't matter if this is running and
     CreateItem call returns 200.
}
```

**Please Note:** Normal Controller action not having async calls works perfectly. However, as soon as an async function call is made from within controller Action I get an error.

I have already activated Cross origin request through: `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

Answer (score 0):

You should await the AsynCall method call.

Comment: Ya, that would work. However, the async method takes too long and I don't want user to wait.